# Stopping other goroutines conditionally

Tags: go, concurrency, channel, goroutine

I am in doubt whether all of my spawned goroutines are dying after doing their assigned work.
I have to make two HTTP calls(always), but based on a flag, read the response from either one of them.
what I have done so far is ->

```
    var result error
    resultChannel := make(chan error)

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(1)  // only adding 1, as I don't need to wait for other to complete.

    go func() {
        _, err := // HTTP call ONE
        if flagIsTrue {
            defer wg.Done()
            resultChannel <- err
        }
    }()
    go func() {
        _, err :=  // HTTP call TWO
        if !flagIsTrue {
            defer wg.Done()
            resultChannel <- err
        }
    }()

    go func() {
        wg.Wait()
        close(resultChannel)
    }()

    for err := range resultChannel {
        result = err
    }
```

Hence, I will wait for the corresponding call, and listen to its response only. This is working well, but since the app is deployed on the server, where I guess the main goroutine won't die(henceforth killing other goroutines), my main concern is whether the other ignorable thread will die or not after it will get the response from HTTP call(afaik, we need to tell go that a goroutine needs to die).
My concerns:

1. The assumption(true acc to me) that the main thread does not terminate after serving one of these calls.
2. Will the ignorable(response is, but necessary to trigger the API call) thread die or not?
3. Should I use a select case to handle this, if yes then how(other suggestions are welcome)?

Comment: Your example doesn't show where `flagIsTrue` comes from or how it's set, which is extremely vital to your example being ok or not. In general the goroutine that sends on a channel should also be responsible for closing it.

Comment: @super The flag is being set prior to spawning goroutines.
Also, the channel will be closed, I am concerned about the goroutine.

Comment: If the flag is never altered, this should be safe since only one goroutine write to result channel. It does however raise the question why you have a waitgroup at all. Why not simply receive one value on the resultchannel and move on?

Comment: @super I think I misunderstood the concepts of concurrency, can you explain a bit why not writing into a channel will make sure that this is safe. I was under the impression that the goroutine will still live.
for the followUp point, are you suggesting to create a single goroutie, make both API calls and then write the response into the channel based on the flag .

Comment: When the function executed by a goroutine ends, the goroutine is no longer alive. So in your example, if the goroutine doesn't write to the result channel it will simply stop. If it on the other hand would try to write to the resultChannel it would block and wait until someone receives the value on the other end, thus staying alive. But trying to send on a closed channel will also cause a panic, hence the rule of thumb that the writing side should be in charge of closing the channel.

Comment: To clarify, there would only be a problem if both goroutines would try to write to the resultChannel since your code does not handle that scenario and would close the channel before reading the second value.

Answer (score 1):

If the `flagIsTrue` is set before creating the goroutines, then only one of the goroutines will be able to write to the channel. The other one will not attempt to write to the channel, and thus will terminate.

You could simply move the check for the flag outside, and create one goroutine based on the flag.

Comment: yes the flag is set before spawning the goroutines, and in the current case, only one is writing in the channel. If I will create a single goroutine, should I make both API calls in this single goroutine?

Comment: One goroutine with an `if flag { url1 } else {url2}` should do

Comment: it is necessary to make both API calls. reading response is conditional.
are you suggesting to create a single goroutie, make both API calls and then write the response into the channel based on the flag

Comment: If you have to call both API calls, then what you're doing is correct.